# Is it possible to pass popen() a string and have it return null?

Tags: c++, linux, popen

While working on line/branch coverage for a unit test, I came across the following code

```
bool run_command(char *command)
{
    FILE *handle = popen(command, "r");
    if (handle == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
```

I've tried many different commands such as

```
"cat /dev/null | head"
```

but nothing seems to cause popen to fail. I also wrote a Python script, test.py,

```
for i in range(10000):
    print(i)
```

and passed "python test.py | head" to popen(). This causes a "broken pipe" error, but popen still returns a valid address.

Is it possible to pass a command string to popen function that will cause it to return null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.  [glibc's `popen`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/b92a49359f33a461db080a33940d73f47c756126/libio/iopopen.c) ultimately calls [`posix_spawn`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html), whose documentation says that it only fails if `fork()` fails.  And that would have nothing to do with the filename.

Likewise, there are a few other ways that `popen` can fail before calling `posix_spawn`, but they aren't related to the filename; only conditions like running out of memory or file descriptors.